# Apps deployed on heroku

Tags: heroku

Will my apps which I deployed on Heroku be available after the elimination of free tier/plans?
If yes, in addition to this, will I be able to build and make changes to the same applications?

Comment: There are some other similar services with free tiers, like [Adaptable.io](https://adaptable.io) and Render.

Comment: I've heard of Render but Adaptable.io is somehow new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your apps are running on free dynos and you don't upgrade, and you aren't eligible as a student, [they will not be available](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours):

> Starting November 28, 2022, free Heroku Dynos, free Heroku Postgres, and free Heroku Data for Redis® plans will no longer be available. If you have apps using any of these resources, you must [upgrade to paid plans](https://help.heroku.com/81MBEG7L/how-do-i-upgrade-from-heroku-s-free-tier-and-begin-using-paid-resources) by this date to ensure your apps continue to run and retain your data. For students, we will announce a new program by the end of September. See [our blog](https://blog.heroku.com/next-chapter) and [FAQ](https://help.heroku.com/RSBRUH58/removal-of-heroku-free-product-plans-faq) for more info.

The [referenced blog post](https://blog.heroku.com/next-chapter) contains a bit more info (emphasis added):

> Starting October 26, 2022, we will begin deleting inactive accounts and associated storage for accounts that have been inactive for over a year. Starting November 28, 2022, we plan to stop offering free product plans and plan to *start shutting down free dynos and data services*. We will be sending out a series of email communications to affected users.